# Accessing jquery variable outside success function throws null

Tags: jquery, ajax

I researched on this question in forums but could not succeed with applying code in answers given by techies. I am trying to access a variable which is inside jquery success function. It throws null as it was assigned null on initialisation. How can I access data value out side ajax call?  Also my Stringified result shows "/" slashes in json string. How can I remove slashes in code. I tried applying regex, replacing / with quotes but no use. Please suggest.

```
var details=null;

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Default/GetDetails",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                details = JSON.stringify(data);            
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.statusText);
            }
        });
    alert(details)
```

Comment: This is not duplicate of Getting response from ajax call. I am able to get response successfully.I get data in success function and I want to use that response outside ajax function..

Comment: It is a duplicate. If you read that question, you'll learn why you can't do what you're trying, and how to do it properly.

Comment: You're alerting before the AJAX call has completed, because AJAX is asynchronous.

Comment: There is no need to parse the `data` within the ajax since you have mentioned `dataType` as `json`.

Answer (score 2):

The normal execution will **not wait for the ajax block to complete execution**.
so the value of details will be alerted even **before the result is assigned** by ajax. 
That is why the alert shows null as result.

if you want to alert the result of details u can call it inside the ajax call.

Answer (score -4):

try to add on more option in your ajax call

```
async:false
```

Comment: As this will lock the UI thread it's a generally bad idea and - first and foremost - a bad user experience!